# custom mod_jk forwarding

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

i want to be able to forward url such as

```
http://external_url.com/auth => http://internal_url.com:8080/app/auth
https://external_url.com/w/my-account => https://internal_url.com:8080/app/LogIn.do
https://external_url.com/w/forgot-password => https://internal_url.com:8080/app/ForgotPassword.do
https://external_url.com/w/register-user => https://internal_url.com:8080/app/CustomerRegistration.do
http://external_url.com/w/logout =>  https://internal_url.com:8080/app/LogIn.do
```

I am already able to forward the standard mirror url to the tomcat apps, but unable to do so for the custom external_url, any ideas?

I tried using `ProxyPathMatch`:

```
ProxyPathMatch ^(/\/w\/forgot\-password)$ http://internal_url.com:8080 /app/ForgotPassword.do
```

but Apache complains saying its incorrect.

much appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 0):

mod_jk isn't like mod_proxy in that you can rewrite the URL in this way. You can do something like this:

```
JkMount /auth  myAuthApp
```

And then define in worker.properties the appropriate application:

```
worker.list=myAuthApp
worker.myAuthApp.host=internal_url.com
worker.myAuthApp.port=8080
```

But your tomcat application must be able to listen on the right context path. In this case it will be /auth, not /app/auth.

You can do all sorts of neat forwarding, using cookies, URIs and much more. But the application will still get the original path and must be able to respond to it.

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html

Comment: As a followup, you can use RewriteRule with [L,PT] to do rewriting and then pass the rewritten path into mod_jk.